# Warning:Cannot modify header information-headers already sent by (output started at (/themes/kaboodle/functions/admin-setup.php

Tags: php, regex, wordpress-theming, wordpress

**Warning Message :**

> **Warning:Cannot modify header information-headers already sent by (output started at (/themes/kaboodle/functions/admin-setup.php:174) in /wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 940**

There is seems to an warning in line number 174 of file `admin-setup.php` which is written as below :

```
echo '<link href="'. get_template_directory_uri() . '/styles/'. $style . '.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />' . "\n\n";
```

i have checked the admin-setup file with any hidden whitespace on php quotes() but still error is persisting.
Could anyone help me out to solve this warning message.
for reference i am putting lines below those are required to check for such error.

Line 174 :

```
*echo '<link href="'. get_template_directory_uri() . '/styles/'. $style . '.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />' . "\n\n";*
```

Re-direct function written as:

```
function woo_themeoptions_redirect () {
    // Do redirect
    header('Location: ' . admin_url() . 'admin.php?page=woothemes');
} // End woo_themeoptions_redirect()
```

Comment: **Need to Know if i can resolve by changing the statement written with Echo**. i tried to refer print/echo part of below link  *http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php* but unable to solve the same in my cache

Comment: you can't use `header` function after outputting => echoing something

Comment: Are you trying to include CSS links, then redirect the page? If so, why? But anyway, you can echo a meta redirect instead of using header.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should use `wp_enqueue_style` to add styles, like so

```
function my_styles_function() 
{
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style-name', get_template_directory_uri() . 'somestyle.css");
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_styles_function' );
```

Second, redirects should be done with `wp_safe_redirect` on `admin_init` or `init` to ensure there is no output before redirect is supposed to happen. For example

```
function my_redirect()
{
       wp_safe_redirect('link_here');
}

add_action('admin_init', 'my_redirect'); // for admin
add_action('init', 'my_redirect'); // for frontend
```

Also, what is the point of echoing style before redirecting?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can solve it the mistakes to that error are

> 1.spaces before

```
<?php ?>
```

> 2.html contents before header
>
> 3.anything echoed before header

you have to remove those

but even after that it show you the same error you can use javascript redirect like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.location.assign('your desired location');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 header('Location: ' . admin_url() . 'admin.php?page=woothemes');
```

you can not use that, after you echoed anything. The `echo` sends the header (as most servers send their output in pieces) and therfore you can't modify it anymore with a `header()` command.